# converting between date formats

Tags: php, mysql

how would you convert a date stored as

2011-01-18 11:51:41

into

18-01-2011 11:51:41

using PHP?

many thanks in advance!

Comment: A date is not stored as anything but just a date. How it looks depends on display formatting. Internally a data is just a number (unless you store it as a string/varchar, in which case it it not a date).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('2011-01-18 11:51:41'));
```

Comment: The problem with this is that on 32-bit servers dates after 2038 will become January 1st 1970.

Answer (score 4):

More reliable than using strtotime(), assuming you're on PHP 5.3+

```
$oldtime = date_parse_from_format('Y-m-d h:i:s', '2011-01-18 11:51:41');
$newtime = date('d-m-Y h:i:s', $time);
```

However, the date format you're converting FROM suggests it's coming from a MySQL datetime field, in which case you could also do:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(yourfield, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

and save yourself a full roundtrip in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the old date to UNIX time with `strtotime()`, then output it in the new format with `date()`

```
$olddate = "2011-01-18 11:51:41";
$newdate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($olddate));
echo $newdate;

// 18-01-2011 11:51:41
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$your_date = "2011-01-18 11:51:41";
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($your_date));
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/7e67c.php)