# Date format with MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, date-format

I have a date format as like given below:

Sat Feb 27 21:39:24 +0000 2010

I have inserted this as TEXT in my database. Is there any way to use the database content as date? Because I have to run the query to find latest date or old date. But I am unable to do this because it's type is TEXT.

If the above query is not possible then tell me how the given format into mysql database as date and time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [check this link ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) mysql documentation AND [THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836126/converting-between-date-formats)

Comment: I have checked that links. All functions works only for specified format of the date and string. Those functions are not solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

I can't tell you exactly which format to use since your example has a 2 digit day, so I don't know if it will represent single digit day values, for example does it use 01 or 1.

But here are a couple of options:

```
-- two digit day
select STR_TO_DATE(your_column,'%a %b %d %k:%i:%s +0000 %Y') from your_table;

-- one to two digit day
select STR_TO_DATE(your_column,'%a %b %e %k:%i:%s +0000 %Y') from your_table;
```

Examples:

```
mysql> -- two digit day
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('Wed Mar 07 12:07:03 +0000 2012','%a %b %d %k:%i:%s +0000 %Y');
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('Wed Mar 07 12:07:03 +0000 2012','%a %b %d %k:%i:%s +0000 %Y') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-03-07 12:07:03                                                        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> -- one to two digit day
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('Wed Mar 7 12:07:03 +0000 2012','%a %b %e %k:%i:%s +0000 %Y');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('Wed Mar 7 12:07:03 +0000 2012','%a %b %e %k:%i:%s +0000 %Y') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-03-07 12:07:03                                                       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CONVERT function, for example :

```
INSERT INTO table(dateField) VALUES ( CONVERT("Sat Feb 27 21:39:24 +0000 2010",DATETIME) )
```

Comment: I am not getting the solution.